# How Do I Get My Python Web Server To Open Files In It's Directory

Tags: python, html, sockets, ftp, webserver

I am attempting to build a web server using python to host a website.
But there is a flaw in my code which I cannot seem to find an answer to.
That flaw is opening files in the same directory of the web server script.
Here is the code:

```
import socket

host, port = '', 80
website = '''
<a href='README.txt'>Read me file</a>
'''
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
print('SERVER STARTED ON PORT {}'.format(port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    clientconnection, clientaddress = s.accept()
    r = clientconnection.recv(1024)
    print(r)    
    response = """
HTTPS/1.1 200 OK

{}
""".format(website)
    clientconnection.sendall(bytes(response.encode()))
    clientconnection.close()
```

The links are working to other sites.
Any Ideas?
Thx in advance

Comment: There is this neat trick in python 2: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` which will serve all the files in the folder. in python 3: `python3.6 -m http.server`

Comment: I'd recommend using Flask or Django. They'll handle a lot of this kind of stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks I will cherish this information much

Answer (score 0):

There is something called `SimpleHTTPServer`. As Rafael Barros said. You should also then create a file titled: `index.html`. If you don't have an index.html file in the directory, then all files and
directories will be listed.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it myself

Comment: Well I am not really sure. This would take a `lot` of time. There's also something called `BaseHttpServer`. With this, you can do a lot more stuff (setting headers etc.) As I said, using `SimpleHTTPServer` or `BaseHttpServer` will do the trick for you. But I sadly do not know if doing this yourself is possible since you do not have the functions.

Comment: What do you mean functions